# Searching nested property's values through the class array

Tags: matlab

Assume we have array of class objects. Our class is a subclass of the handle class. We can use findobj function to find handle objects by first-level property's value. It's ok.

For example, a class structure:

```
className
|——property1
|——property2
|——structproperty1
———|——innerProperty1
———|——innerProperty2
```

findobj function will return results only if every structure field is filled. Below is an example.

```
b: 1x1234 className

structToFind = struct ('innerProperty1', 10, 'innerProperty2', 20);
H = findobj (b, 'structproperty1', structToFind);
```

But I want to search className handle objects by innerProperty1. Is there any way to do it?

**UPDATE #1**

To avoid misunderstation I want to search through the object array without setting innerProperty2, for example. But it will return class object handlers that have an exact structure ('innerProperty1', 10). So if my object.structproperty1.innerProperty2 is set a function will not return an object handler for the example below.

```
structToFind = struct ('innerProperty1', 10);
H = findobj (b, 'structproperty1', structToFind);
```

Comment: you could convert className to cell using `struct2cell` which should allow you to use findobj on the innerProperty struct

Comment: @GameOfThrows className is a name of class, I can't convert class handler to cell

Comment: Try  `H = findobj (b, 'structproperty1', structToFind,'-depth',inf);`, but tbh no idee if thats working for your hirarchy

Comment: @marcowassmer -depth property is infinite by default, look at an update#1

Comment: ok, diffrent idea: `{ b{cellfun(@(x) x.structproperty1.innerProperty1==10,b)}}`

Comment: @marcowassmer b is not a cell array, it is an array of my class objects

Comment: @alxndr_k even better then you should be able to work with logical indexing like so: `b([b.structproperty1.innerProperty1]==10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier solution. 
I used `findobj(H,'-function',fh)`. We can use function handle for filtering the object. So for this test example it should be something like this:

```
b: 1x1234 className

H = findobj (b, '-function', 'structproperty1', @(x) isfield(x, 'innerProperty1') );
```

[mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.findobj.html](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.findobj.html)